# Access Fastlane

Tags: java, android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, nokiax

I am currently developing a Launcher for Nokia X. How do I integrate the FastLane feature of Nokia X onto it. I already do have a base for the Launcher, and already had been tested against Android 4.1.2 (16). By the way I've already checked [here](http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/Java/developers-guides/data-handling/share-api/fastlane-integration.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically your link is to Asha platform, so its not valid with Nokia X.

With Nokia X, you don't really have any dedicated API for Fastlane, however, if you check the [Notifications part is Design library](http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/nokia-x-ui/notifications.html), it says that "Notification drawer in Android shows contracted notifications that can be expanded. The Nokia X Fastlane collects all notifications and other recent activities. If the app has defined an expanded notification, it will only show on Fastlane; Lock screen will show the contracted version.", thus you indeed can make notifications which would open the app.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look of Accessibility framework and focus on AccessibilityEvents with type "TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED"